# Why catch specific Java exceptions unless specific handling is needed?

Tags: java

Here is the code taken from https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java

```
public void automaticallyCloseResource() {
    File file = new File("./tmp.txt");
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);) {
        // use the inputStream to read a file

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

If all the catch handlers are essentially doing the same, I don't see why we catch each specific exception separately instead of simply catching the generic base Exception class.

Essentially, if you are not looking for properties/methods/anything of the specific exception, why not just catch the generic Exception?

Answer (score 3):

For the given sample, having two `catch` blocks is really redundant, yes. It could easily handled in one single `catch` block for `IOException`.

But let's assume we have a method like this:

```java
public final Optional<Status> doSomething( final String... arguments )
  throws IOException, SQLException, PatternSyntaxException
{
  …
}
```

We don't care what the method is really doing, we just assume that it will not check the `arguments` for `null` – meaning we can see a `NullPointerException` under some circumstances.

Let's use that method now, with the error handling that you suggest:

```java
try
{
  final var status = doSomething( arguments ).get();  
}
catch( final Exception e ) // Not good!
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
```

Looks perfectly ok – but `handleExcpectedException()` may be called with some 'unexpected' exceptions, too: with a `NullPointerException` or with a `NoSuchElementException`.

Ok, second attempt:

```java
try
{
  final var status = doSomething( arguments ).get();  
}
catch( final IOException e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
catch( final SQLException e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
catch( final PatternSyntaxException e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
catch( final NullPointerException e )
{
  handleUnexpectedException( e );
}
catch( final NoSuchElementException e )
{
  handleUnexpectedException( e );
}
```

Confessed, that's a lot of lines, for nearly nothing. Therefore Java 5 (or Java 6?) introduced a way to combine the `catch` for multiple exceptions that are handled the same way:

```java
try
{
  final var status = doSomething( arguments ).get();  
}
catch( final IOException | SQLException | PatternSyntaxException e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
catch( final NullPointerException | NoSuchElementException e )
{
  handleUnexpectedException( e );
}
```

But why do we want to list the exceptions at all? Why not just having two categories and handle them like this:

```java
try
{
  final var status = doSomething( arguments ).get();  
}
catch( final RuntimeException e )
{
  handleUnexpectedException( e );
}
catch( final Exception e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
```

That's because we want that unexpected exceptions will bubble up when they occur! We want (at least, I want) that a program, that behaves completely unexpected, will fail fast! And loud!

The `throws` clause in the signature of `doSomething()` tells us, that it may throw three different types of exceptions (and usually, the respective documentation will tell us, why). So we can prepare our code to handle them. Just log them and terminate is the easiest way, but perhaps we know how to recover from the error condition and can retry, or we have an alternative processing, or whatever.

But the `NullPointerException` either indicates that there is a programming bug in the code of `doSomething()`, or we have not read the documentation properly and fed a `null` into it. Both is nothing that can be fixed during runtime.

And the `NoSuchElementException` is clearly caused by a bug in our code: `doSomething()` returns an instance of `Optional`, and that can be empty; calling `Optional::get` on the result without checking it is definitely a bug! And I want to see this bug soon, in order to be able to fix it soon!

A `catch` block for `Exception` may swallow these exceptions and they will never surface – and I will never find the reason why my program returns sometimes unexpected results …

---

So the recommendation is to catch only those exceptions that are expected at this level (either they are declared with a `throws` clause or described in the documentation) and that could be handled in the current `catch` block.

To 'handle' an exception means that the system is brought back into a stable state!

Logging a `FileNotFoundException` in the `catch` block and then continuing after that `catch` block like the (non-existing!) file was found and opened is calling for desaster!

If you just catch an exception locally because you want to enrich the error message, you should not log it; just wrap it and re-throw:

```java
…
catch( final FileNotFoundException e )
{
  final var message = "MatrixReport output file %s could not be found!".formatted( e.getMessage() );
  throw new MyApplicationError( message, e );
}
```

So finally, when I would use `doSomething()` (without fixing the already mentioned bugs), my code may look like this (assuming that the `FileNotFoundException` is documented):

```java
try
{
  final var status = doSomething( arguments ).get();  
}
catch( final FileNotFoundException e )
{
  final var message = "MatrixReport output file %s could not be found!".formatted( e.getMessage() );
  throw new MyApplicationError( message, e );
}
catch( final IOException | SQLException | PatternSyntaxException e )
{
  handleExpectedException( e );
}
```

---

Ok, we handle only exceptions that we can handle, and let the rest bubbling up … but who will now take care of these exceptions?

When this happens in the main thread, the exception that terminates it will be printed to `stdout`. Great! And what about the other threads?

Usually, these will die silently …

So you quite often see the recommendations to have a `catch` block for `RuntimeException` in a thread's `run()` method, like this:

```java
public final void run()
{
  try
  {
    // Do this thread's work …
  }
  catch( final RuntimeException e )
  {
    log.error( e );
  }
}
```

But this can be achieved easier: you can set an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` instance to the `Thread`! See [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)). You can do this even implicitly by assigning the thread to a specific [`ThreadGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) that provides an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (you have to implement your own class that extends `ThreadGroup` for that), or you have a [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that does the assigning for you …

---

Oh, before I forget: I introduced `handleExpectedException()` for a reason, instead of simply using `log.error()`: if you do not fix the status that is indicated by the exception, you may not continue the regular flow of the code! Logging an exception is ***not*** handling it!

This means `handleException()` will not return regularly in most cases; perhaps it throws an instance of `MyApplicationError`, too, or it will call `System::exit` (really nasty when you are in a web application … don't do it!) or whatever is appropriate …

Answer (score 2):

I assume the writer of the article is simply trying to make a point of catching the most specific exceptions first, then the more generic ones. This is not just a best practice, but a Java language requirement as the code won't compile otherwise due to having defined unreachable code blocks.

In the particular code block quoted by you, it's not necessary and you might as well just catch `IOException`, since `FileNotFoundException` extends it + the behaviour to be expected once an exception is caught is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Given that in that particular example there is no difference in handling exceptions, there is no utility in making distinction between them. As FileNotFoundException is IOException subtype, catching only IOException would be just fine.

Now, in general, if you do not know how to handle catched exception. Do not push orginal exception on caller of your method. Do not add "throws Something" to method signature. Don't even bother to log exception unless you are able to add specific causes of the exception. The thing you should do is to rethrown them as RuntimeException. Like this example:

```
public void automaticallyCloseResource() {
    File file = new File("./tmp.txt");
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);) {
        // use the inputStream to read a file
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException("An error handling './tmp.txt'", e);
    }
}
```

**So what is the logic in this?**

If you do not know how to handle this IOException right here right now - any caller of your method is going to have even less knowledge how to handle it. Thus you should not not bother people with unnecessary boiler plate, abd that is why there is no "throws IOException" clause. Instead catched exception is wrapped by aditional RuntimeException. There is also no logging of us doing so.

**And who is going to handle that RuntimeException?**

Well every thread in code should have a top level exception handler. Nothing smart, just a generic handler:

```
try {
  // my app code here
} 
catch(MyCustomException exc) {
  // do smart stuff here
}
catch(RuntimeExceptio exc) {
  log.error("An unexpected has happened", exc);
  // rethrow or consume here
}
```

Thus logging of "unrecoverable" exceptions is postponed to the highest catch level. Usual practice of loging and rehtrowing exceptions only leads to logs being polluted with same exception multiple times. Given that all Java exceptions carry perfect information where they were raised, unless you can add useful stuff to log, don't bother to log them except on top level.

**And finally why shouldn't you catch all Exceptions, Errors or Throwables?**

Again, as general advice, your code should catch (and rethrow) only exceptions which are directly raised by code you invoked. Generic Exception/Throwable block will catch all other exceptions which you have no chance to handle properly. System stuff like OutOfMemoryException. Those exceptions are unrecoverable and you tempting with them will only lead to your application being less stable and harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that this is pointless as written.

They should probably have written `log.error("TODO: Handle FileNotFound", e);` or `// TODO: Handle missing files` so that you wouldn't be tempted to think that `log.error(e);` is the end goal rather than a stand-in.

It makes more sense when you look at the suggested rewrite:

```
public void closeResourceInFinally() {
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("./tmp.txt");
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        // use the inputStream to read a file

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that the author wanted to catch a `FileNotFoundException` while initializing, and an `IOException` while closing.

If the first example had only caught the `IOException` because it would amount to the same, wouldn't you have asked "wait, why does it suddenly catch FileNotFoundException now?"

By including both in the original example, it's easier to see how the first maps to the second.